# I am trying to make a visited state to my nav bar. This sounds easy, but the code I have is weird

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a visited state to my nav bar. This sounds easy, but the code I have is weird. I have created a navigation bar with a drop - down menu and I would like a visited state so I can remove the headings and people still know where they are. I might just be overlooking something, but I have searched many forums, youtube, and referenced books and it seems all roads lead to stackoveflow.

Here is the HTML from my contact page.

```
   <div id="nav">
       <div id="nav_wrapper">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>
            <a href="concept.html">Concept</a></li><li>
            <a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li><li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li><li>
            <a href="find.html">Find Us<img src="rsz_1wht_arrow.png" alt="small arrow"/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="catering.html">Catering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#nav{
    background-color: #830300;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #830300;

}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: blue;
}
#nav ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
#nav ul li a,visited {
    color: #e6ee17;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #830300;
    border: 5px solid #e6ee17;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Any help would be great Thanks! p.s. I am using a generic address and took out my footer for obvious reasons.

Comment: `#nav ul li a,visited {` should be `#nav ul li a:visited {` What issue(s) are you running into?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what you're trying to do? It's not totally clear to me. So you have a navigation bar where menu items contain drop down. Once they're visited, you're trying to hide them? Or are you just trying to do a more standard change of text or background color after an element has been clicked?

Comment: I just want whatever page the user is on to stay highlighted, I seem to be lost in my own code.

Comment: How are you assigning the current page to the menu item `li` or `a`? Are you manually putting in a class for the current page, i.e. `current-page`? Also, I edited down your code to only the relevant information (once the edit is approved).

Comment: li and the style sheet is used on 7 pages, not using seperate classes and ty for the edit.

Comment: Check my answer to your question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I was commenting on your answer disinfor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can add a class to the `li` so it remains "active". I used the "contact.html" as the example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
       <div id="nav_wrapper">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>
            <a href="concept.html">Concept</a></li><li>
            <a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li><li class="current-page">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li><li>
            <a href="find.html">Find Us<img src="rsz_1wht_arrow.png" alt="small arrow"/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="catering.html">Catering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav ul li:hover,
#nav ul li.current-page {
    background-color: #000;
    color: blue;
}
```

So, you would simply add a class `current-page` to corresponding link in each of your HTML files.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zu6bjmkb/

Comment: I tried that, but not working either. Thanks I guess I'll just keep  playing around and hopefully I will fix it.

Comment: I tried that and see what you were going for, but the problem is, say I head to the menu page the find us page is highlighted which is two links away, but I learned something new thanks.

Comment: @user3758480 I'm not sure what you mean? Here's a fiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/zu6bjmkb/